# ElasticSearch: strange search behaviour when using snowball analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, snowball

So let's say I have an ElasticSearch index defined like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "example": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "snowball"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/example/1' -d '{
  "text": "foo bar organization"
}'
```

When I search for "foo organizations" with snowball analyzer, both keywords match as expected:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/test/example/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "text": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "foo organizations",
        "analyzer": "snowball"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "text": {}
    }
  }
}'

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.015912745,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "example",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.015912745,
        "_source": {
          "text": "foo bar organization"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "text": [
            "<em>foo</em> bar <em>organization</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I search for only "organizations" I don't get any result at all which is very weird:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/test/example/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "text": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "organizations",
        "analyzer": "snowball"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "text": {}
    }
  }
}'

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

However, if I search for "bars" it still hits:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/test/example/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "text": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "bars",
        "analyzer": "snowball"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "text": {}
    }
  }
}'

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.10848885,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "example",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.10848885,
        "_source": {
          "text": "foo bar organization"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "text": [
            "foo <em>bar</em> organization"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I guess the difference between "bar" and "organization" is that "organization" is stemmed to "organ" while "bar" is stemmed to itself. But how do I get the proper behaviour so that 2nd search hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text "foo bar organization" is getting indexed twice - in the field **text** and in the field **_all**. The field **text** is using snowball analyzer, and the field **_all** is using standard analyzer. Therefore after analysis of the test record the field **_all** contains tokens: "foo", "bar", and "organization". During search specified snowball analyzer converts "foo" into "foo", "bars" into "bar" and "organization" into "organ". So, words "foo" and "bars" in the query match the test record and the term "organization" doesn't. Highlighting is performed on per field basis independently from searching and that's why word "organization" is getting highlighted in the first result.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. Is there a way I can look at actual tokens that my index has? And can I tell ES to use snowball for **_all** column?

Comment: There is no simple way to take a look at actual tokens in an index, but it's possible to see how text is analyzed using Analyze API (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html). You can set snowball analyzer for the *_all* field during index creation https://gist.github.com/2043721. Alternatively, snowball can be set as a default analyzer for all fields https://gist.github.com/2043697.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use analyzer at index time than search time..Map your text field to snow ball analyzer and then index. This will create some tokens for organization which includes organizations.It works for me